# Globally filter the whole site by tag

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

I am looking for an easy way to allow visitors of our Drupal 6-based website to filter all displayed obejcts globally by a tag from a given taxonomy ("featured topics"). This way a user could eg. select the tag "marketing" from a drop-down-list, which is located somewhere near the navigation, and the system would filter all pages, lists and views by the selected tag, across the session, until the user unsets the filter. Having a filter set should be reflected by the theme, but that would be the next task, I guess.

Does anybody know a module which does something like that or could help me here? Is there any easy way to get this functionality (without hacking my way deeply through drupal's guts in weeks of hard work)?

Thank you in advance!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

There are literally hundreds of modules that offer "filter by tag features". I am not aware of one that does what you wish as turnkey, but I am confident there is one that has exactly your interface and workflow, either OOTB, or configurable.

If you were considering views (you were, weren't you?) views offers so called "exposed filters" which allow any filter (filters being: created by Foo, edited after 24-dec, or _has tag Bar), where your users can select such filters from e.g. a dropdown box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, berkes. Exactly, that's the way I'm trying to solve it. I have exposed filters for the taxonomy. Now the problem remains how to link the exposed filters of all views together, so that the filter persists if the visitor moves from "news" to "events" for example. I might have to store the filter-selection to the session and then recall and apply it to the other view - across all views in the whole website. That'd be it. Still, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I would suggest to re-post another question where you ask how to get taxonomy-tags persistent. That is a slightly different matter and more specific then what you seem to have asked above. I am sorry that I do not know the answer to "how to make tags persistent"